# malloc: *** error for object: pointer being freed was not allocated *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Tags: c++, память

Написал аналог класса String, но при вызове метода test2() происходит ошибка. Чувствую, что я чего-то не догоняю в том как работает память в C++. Разъясните, пожалуйста, почему возникает ошибка.

```
#include <iostream>

struct String {
    String (String const& other) {
        size = other.size;
        if (size > 0) {
            str = new char[size + 1];
            str[size] = '\0';

            const char * i = other.str;
            while (i != other.str + other.size) {
                str[i - other.str] = *i;
                i++;
            };
        } else {
            str = 0;
        }
    }

    String(const char *str = "") {
        size = 0;
        this->str = 0;
        size = lengthOfStr(str);
        this->str = (size > 0) ? cpStr(str, size) : 0;
    }

    String(size_t n, char c) {
        size = n;
        str = new char[size + 1];
        str[size] = '\0';
        char * i = str;
        while (i - str < size) {
            *i = c;
            i++;
        };
    }

    ~String() {
        if (str != 0)
            delete [] str;
        str = 0;
        size = 0;
    }

    void append(String &other) {
        size_t newSz = size + other.size;
        char *newStr = new char[newSz + 1];
        newStr[newSz] = '\0';

        const char * i = str;
        while (i != str + size) {
            newStr[i - str] = *i;
            i++;
        };

        i = other.str;
        while (i != other.str + other.size) {
            newStr[size + i - other.str] = *i;
            i++;
        };

        delete [] str;
        size = newSz;
        str = newStr;
    }

    size_t lengthOfStr(const char * const str) {
        const char * i = str;
        while (*i != '\0') {
            i++;
        };
        return i - str;
    }

    char* cpStr(const char * const str, size_t strSz) {
        char *newStr = new char[strSz + 1];
        newStr[strSz] = '\0';

        const char * i = str;
        while (i != str + strSz) {
            newStr[i - str] = *i;
            i++;
        };

        return newStr;
    }

    size_t size;
    char *str;
};

int test2() {
    String ten_spaces;
    ten_spaces = String(10, ' ');
    std::cout << ten_spaces.str << "\n";
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    test2();
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Скриншот ошибки]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А происходит много плохого.

```
ten_spaces = String(10, ' ');
```

Здесь

1. Создаётся новая строка (экземпляр которой я обзову `tmp`). Выделяется память под десять пробелов.
2. Вызывается оператор присваивания `ten_spaces.operator =(tmp);`. Стандартный оператор присваивания вида `T::operator =(T const& b)` поэлементно присваивает все поля, поэтому `tmp.str == ten_spaces.str` - один и тот же указатель.
3. Потом уничтожается `tmp`. Вместе с этим освобождается `tmp.str`.

А когда будет освобождаться `ten_spaces`, она попробует удалить ту же память и... боль.

Как это решить?

1. Всегда копировать строку, объявив свои копирующий конструктор и оператор присваивания. Неэффективно по памяти и времени, но по крайней мере от такой проблемы избавимся.
2. Использовать умные указатели вместо простых, а именно `shared_ptr<char>`, потому что на одну и ту же область памяти может приходиться несколько пользователей, и не ясно, кто когда её забудет окончательно освободит. Выгодно по памяти и производительности, но немного хуже оригинального (но неработающего :( ) варианта.
3. (Добавлено) Использовать всю мощь C++11 и делать так:

Просто грамотно использовать rvalue-references:

```
ten_spaces = std::move(String(10, ' '));
```